# How can I redirect url from button with specific attribute value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use Slider Revolutions tabs to redirect to a page. 
The buttons (tabs) have this structure:

```
<div data-liindex="1" data-liref="rs-12" class="tp-tab selected" style="width: 170px; height: 50px; left: 190px; top: 0px;"><span class="tp-tab-title">ARMENIA</span></div>
```

The buttons defer from eachother by **`data-liindex`** parameter. 0, 1, 2,...

I tried this code but cannot figure out how to getElement by the custom id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("1").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.google.com";
    };
</script>
```

I cannot alter the button code though. Its generated by Slider Revolution so I cannot add parameters to it any more than what it is now.

Comment: You have to put the id into the tag you want to target.
<div id='1' data-liindex="1" data-liref="rs-12" class="tp-tab selected" style="width: 170px; height: 50px; left: 190px; top: 0px;"><span class="tp-tab-title">ARMENIA</span></div>

Comment: No way to target this parameter data-liindex="1" specifically?

Comment: Use `document.querySelector(‘[data-liindex=“1”]’)`.

Comment: Can you accept my answer?

Comment: Its not working. The slider disappear after I enter the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code did the job. Need to be inserted in the SETTINGS of the current slider, not in the slides separatly.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('body').on('click', '.tp-tab', function () {
        switch($(this).attr("data-liindex")) {
            case "1":
            window.location.href = "https://google.com/";
        break;
            case "2":
            window.location.href = "https://blizzard.com/";
        break;
            default:
        break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select element with  data- attribute you can do like:

```
document.querySelector("[data-liindex='1']");
```

Or you want to select the element by ID you can add the id to the tag you want to select:

```
<div data-liindex="1" data-liref="rs-12" class="tp-tab selected" style="width: 170px; height: 50px; left: 190px; top: 0px;"><span class="tp-tab-title">ARMENIA</span></div>

document.querySelector('#1')
```

Comment: **document.querySelector("[data-liindex='1']").onclick = function () {location.href = "www.google.com";};**
its not waiting for a click on the tab, its just fired up when slider is shown and returning TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null in the console

Answer (score 1):

Simplified the HTML for the demo. Does this help? (NOTE: Commented out the location.href for the demo)

```js
let arrayUrl = [
  "www.google.com",
  "www.bing.com",
  "www.yahoo.com"
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Add Click Listeners
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tp-tab')).forEach(el => {
     el.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        console.log(`${event.target} - ${event.target.dataset.liindex}`);
        let url = arrayUrl[ event.target.dataset.liindex ];
        console.log(url);
        // location.href = url;
     });
  });

});
```

```html
<div data-liindex="0" data-liref="rs-12" class="tp-tab">ARMENIA
</div>

<div data-liindex="1" data-liref="rs-12" class="tp-tab">Canada
</div>

<div data-liindex="2" data-liref="rs-12" class="tp-tab">Europe
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing happens. Even the console is empty when clicking the buttons.

Comment: Did you run the snippet, is working for me. Obviously you need to uncomment `location.href` for it to actually navigate

Comment: It looks like the code works, but not when inserted in Slider Revolution JS custom code field. Thanks man. Appreciated!

Comment: I will take a look at Slider Revolution. See if we can fix for that